# SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value. - Multiple Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues with the following update statement:

```
UPDATE tblPerson
SET personStatus = 'Candidate'
WHERE PersonID = 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.PersonnelID
    FROM 
        [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.Personnel p
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.LinkedDocuments L WHERE id = p.PersonnelId
                                                AND     SiteName IS NOT NULL
                                                AND     (Document LIKE ('%CV%') 
                                                OR      Document LIKE ('%resume%')
                                                OR      Document LIKE ('%Vitae%')
                                                OR      Document LIKE ('%Cover Letter%'))))
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Not entirely sure what i am doing wrong here, any help would be much appreciate it

Comment: *following update statement:* followed by `SELECT` query. Please add the `UPDATE` query

Comment: The `SELECT` you showed us should not be generating this error.

Comment: Sorry i uploaded the wrong thing, ive updated it now.

Comment: Are you sure that the query used in the where-clause is returning just one value? Execute this one in a separate run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IN` operator

```
UPDATE tblPerson
SET    personStatus = 'Candidate'
WHERE  PersonID IN (SELECT p.PersonnelID
                    FROM   [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.Personnel p
                    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT ID
                                   FROM   [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.LinkedDocuments L
                                   WHERE  id = p.PersonnelId
                                          AND SiteName IS NOT NULL
                                          AND ( Document LIKE '%CV%' --Here
                                                 OR Document LIKE '%resume%'
                                                 OR Document LIKE '%Vitae%'
                                                 OR Document LIKE '%Cover Letter%' )))
```

Also you need to add  parenthesis apply `OR` operator properly. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` operator so it will be evaluated first

Your current `Where` clause will be processed like this

```
WHERE  id = p.PersonnelId
       AND ( SiteName IS NOT NULL AND Document LIKE '%CV%' )
        OR Document LIKE '%resume%'
        OR Document LIKE '%Vitae%'
        OR Document LIKE '%Cover Letter%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=`, since it's returning more than one value. Change it to `IN`

```
UPDATE tblPerson
    SET personStatus = 'Candidate'
    WHERE PersonID IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            p.PersonnelID
        FROM 
            [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.Personnel p
        WHERE 
            EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.LinkedDocuments L WHERE id = p.PersonnelId
                                                    AND     SiteName IS NOT NULL
                                                    AND     (Document LIKE ('%CV%') 
                                                    OR      Document LIKE ('%resume%')
                                                    OR      Document LIKE ('%Vitae%')
                                                    OR      Document LIKE ('%Cover Letter%'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
            UPDATE tblPerson
            SET personStatus = 'Candidate'
            WHERE PersonID = 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    p.PersonnelID
                FROM 
                    [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.Personnel p
                WHERE 
                     PersonID IN (SELECT ID FROM [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.LinkedDocuments L WHERE id = p.PersonnelId
                                                            AND     SiteName IS NOT NULL
                                                            AND     (Document LIKE ('%CV%') 
                                                            OR      Document LIKE ('%resume%')
                                                            OR      Document LIKE ('%Vitae%')
                                                            OR      Document LIKE ('%Cover Letter%'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simply JOIN instead of IN and EXISTS as below:

```
UPDATE tp SET personStatus = 'Candidate'
FROM  tblPerson tp
INNER JOIN [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.Personnel p ON tp.PersonID = p.PersonnelID
INNER JOIN [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.LinkedDocuments L ON id = p.PersonnelId
    AND SiteName IS NOT NULL
    AND (Document LIKE ('%CV%') OR  Document LIKE ('%resume%') OR Document LIKE ('%Vitae%') OR Document LIKE ('%Cover Letter%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Directly update from table 2 to table 1 :

UPDATE tblPerson SET personStatus = 'Candidate'
FROM [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.Personnel P
WHERE p.PersonnelID = tblPerson.PersonID AND 
EXISTS
 (
    SELECT 1 FROM [Beyond-Auckland].dbo.LinkedDocuments L WHERE id =   
    p.PersonnelId  AND SiteName IS NOT NULL  AND 
  (
   Document LIKE ('%CV%') OR
   Document LIKE ('%resume%') OR      
   Document LIKE ('%Vitae%') OR
   Document LIKE ('%Cover Letter%')
  )
)
```